# Flutter: How to move a firebase node - API REST vs SDK

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I have a node in Firebase that has multiple childs and childs of childs. I want to **move all** from one place to another, then I made a function with Firebase REST API, but I would like to optimize it and migrate it to SDK.

The function I'm using with API REST is:

```
 Future<bool> moverLoteActual() async {
    
    //TO READ FROM SOURCE PATH
    final urlLoteActual = '$_PATH_ORIGEN.../loteActual.json?auth=${_prefs.token}';

    final resp = await http.get(urlLoteActual);
    //TODO: Probably I neew an error management here

    //TO COPY IN DESTINATION
    final urlLotesCerrados = '$PATH_DESTINO.../lotesCerrados.json?auth=${_prefs.token}';

    final resp2 = await http.post(urlLotesCerrados, body: resp.body); 
    final decodedData2 = json.decode(resp2.body);
    print(decodedData2);

    //TO DELETE THE SOURCE NODE
    final resp3 = await http.delete(urlLoteActual);
    print(json.decode(resp3.body));

    return true;

  }
```

I tried with SDK but I get a lot of parsing errors and finally I think a sequential approach as I implemented with API REST is not the best way.

How can I get this change of location using SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

First, you need to understand that **snapshot.value is a Map<dynamic,    dynamic>**, then you need to assign the answer (resp) to this type of    map.

Later, you need to copy the node in a new location, then you need to convert the previous Map to a new one of other type    (**Map<String,    dynamic> to write**)

The last step (delete the original node) is easy... the standard function.

```
Future<bool> moverLoteActual() async {

  //TO READ FROM SOURCE PATH 
  Map<dynamic, dynamic> _map = new Map<dynamic, dynamic>();
  Query resp = db.child('$_PATH_ORIGEN.../loteActual');  

  final snapshot = await resp.once();
  _map = snapshot.value;

  //TO COPY IN DESTINATION
  db.child('$PATH_DESTINO.../lotesCerrados')
    .push().update(Map<String, dynamic>.from(_map));

  //TO DELETE THE SOURCE NODE
  db.child('$_PATH_ORIGEN.../loteActual').remove();

  return true;

}
```

PD. db is the Firebase Database Reference